# environment variables in the static website hosted on AWS

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-s3

I have frontend written in the js+html and backend written in go.
The backend is deployed to two different environments (dev & prod).

I would like to deploy the frontend to two different environments also (one should use backend-dev and the second should use backend-prod).

I use github -> aws codepipeline -> aws s3.
I wanted to use environment variables but I can't because the frontend is written in pure js+html.

What is the best way to achieve two environments for static website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem, and one is examining the hosted domain/URL

Here is an example:

I assume that you hosted your frontend like this:

Dev:   https://dev.mywebsite.com
Prod:  https://prod.mywebsite.com

API Dev: https://apidev.mywebsite.com
API Dev: https://apiprod.mywebsite.com

By hosting your frontend in two different subdomains, you should be able to easily decide which API you want to access without needing any environment variable.

Comment: Should I use something like window.location.hostname ?